# AMP alternatives for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, mobile, amp-html

I'm currently working off angular 1.x and have been advised by an SEO expert to improve my sites initial mobile load speed, to do this he suggested using AMP however, looking further into this I've found out it doesn't seem possible to implement AMP in Angular. The web app I'm working on is substantial in size so any major work around may be problematic.

Would be interested in hearing has anyone else run into this and how they've found any alternatives to improving their mobile site speed, any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: What is _AMP_? Also, you should consider reducing the scope of your question to maybe (some) specific problem(s) since many of this type of questions are _closed_ or put _on hold_ as _too broad_.

Comment: (_My guess, it's an Asynchronous Messaging Protocol_) How about loading dependancies only when they are needed, i.e. - **lazy loading**? You can try [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) module for that. Here is a ["Large apps guide"](https://coderwall.com/p/y0zkiw/building-large-apps-with-angularjs) with some suggestions, presentation and examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What AMP is doing isn't ground breaking.  Take the standards that AMP applies, decide what works best for your application and apply them.

- **Gzip**: Your assets
- **Images:** 100kb and below would be ideal.  Use [webP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) file format, for chrome and native android users. Optimize `JPEG` and `PNG` images. Lazy-load images
- **Fonts**: If using webfont provider, check to see how long it takes to download the `css`.
- **Async:** Any scripts that you can

Comment: @chdonncha [google](https://developers.google.com/speed/) has some great documentation to help with optimization.